# How to break scanner for certain statements and run for others

Tags: java

Im a SUPER beginner in programming and was doing some exercises and I need your help. I just simulated an ATM machine in the most basic way. I need your help in the part that says Press 1 Deposit or Press 3 Talk to a representative. I need the Scanner to break after that if user presses 1 or 3 as currently it is set so that if user will press 2 it will send them to the Withdraw statement where you can finish the transaction but right now its still executing for Pressing 1 and 3 and I cant think how to break that or change that. Thanks in advance

```
package june;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER PIN");
        int pin = 9876;
        pin = scr.nextInt();

        if (pin == 9876) {
            System.out.println("Welcome To XYZ Bank! Choose your options for today!");
            System.out.println("To Deposit                                      Press 1");
            System.out.println("To Withdraw                                    Press 2");
            System.out.println("To Talk To a Representative            Press 3");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong Pin") ;
        }
        {
            int enter1 = 1;
                    enter1=scr.nextInt();

            if(enter1==1) {
                System.out.println("Deposit");
            }else if (enter1==2)
                    System.out.println("Enter Withdraw Amount");
            else if(enter1==3)
                System.out.println("Hello! My name is Kismat. How may I help you today?");
            else
                System.out.println("Error. Please Enter Correct Code");

            int withdraw = scr.nextInt();
            int creditBalance=1000;

            if (withdraw<=1000){
                System.out.println("Cashing Out");
            }else if(withdraw<=1200){
                System.out.println("Insufficient Funds. Proceed and Overdraft Charges Will Appy - (For upto $200 above Credit Balance in Checking Account)");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Transaction Incomplete. Insufficient Funds");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of focusing on scanner, what if you move your code related to withdraw amount into code block of `else if (enter1==2)`, in this case mentioned code block will belong to only actions related to cashing out. if user does not choose option2, you will be able to skip the part that you want to skip

Comment: I guess my problem with is that when user enters any number in the console the if else statement for withdraw is still running. Thats what i wanted to be able to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would help you to restructure and break your code up a bit into methods to understand what you should be doing.

at a high level this is kind of what you need:

```
    if(validatePin(getPin()) {
       printMenu();
       while(true) { //loop forever
          int input = getUserSelection();
           if(input == 1) {
              handleDeposit();
              break;
           }
           else if(input == 2) {
              handleWithdrawal();
              break;
           }
           else if(input == 3) {
              handleRepresentative();
              break;
           }
           else {
              handleInputError();
           }
    else {
        handlePinError();
    }
```

If you implement each method you can start to work out the logic and it won't be so difficult to understand what you need to do.

Also excuse the formatting it was hard to type on here..

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes so much sense! I will give it a try!